# How to detect similar cases using multiple variables in R

Tags: r, duplicates, group

I want to detect similar cases by groups in R. This an example of my data. The names are not real:

[image]

In home 1, Steven Montero is duplicated but with a second last name and different trimester. How can I detect this cases in R and select the one in the last trimester?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one simple solution. This exactly solve what you describe in your question with no guarantee that will apply on your real dataset:

Basically we group `Home` and `Relationship` assuming that the duplicate Name is with same `Relationship` we can `arrange` and `slice`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(Home, Relationship) %>% 
  arrange(-Trimester, .by_group = TRUE) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

```
  Home Name                   Relationship Trimester
  <int> <chr>                         <int>     <int>
1     1 Steven Montero Molina             1         2
2     1 Maria Vargas Mendoza              2         1
3     1 Helena Montero Mendoza            3         1
4     2 Tiffany Lopez                     1         1
5     2 Fabiola Linarez Lopez             2         2
6     3 Sharon Segura                     3         1
```

data:

```
structure(list(Home = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L), Name = c("Steven Montero", 
"Maria Vargas Mendoza", "Helena Montero Mendoza", "Steven Montero Molina", 
"Tiffany Lopez", "Fabiola Linares", "Fabiola Linarez Lopez", 
"Sharon Segura"), Relationship = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
3L), Trimester = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```